# Find factorisation into irreducibles of $2, 3, 7$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Tags: ring-theory

I have just proved $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a UFD.

Now I am trying to factorise $2, 3,$ and $7$ into irreducibles in $R$, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I know $7=(3+\sqrt{2})(3-\sqrt{2})$ and $2=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}$ so think I am done factorising these, but don't know how to prove these factors are irreducible. I also feel I found the factors of 7 more through luck than anything else, so wonder if there is a more systematic way to factorise.

Comment: If they factor, their norms factor.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am still confused- for instance for the above, the norm of $(3+\sqrt{2})$ is 11, how do we know this doesn't factor in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$? Or even how do we know $\sqrt{2}$ doesn't? Sorry if this is basic, I am very unfamiliar with this.

Comment: The norm of $3+\sqrt2$ is not $11$. The norm is the product of the number and its conjugate. [But even if it had been $11$, you'd still be done: the norm of a product is the product of the norms, so if the norm is a prime, the number can't be a product.]

Comment: Are we OK now??

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.